# TYPO3 tt_content structure: t3_origuid vs l18n_parent

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I had to import a few posts from one TYPO3 site into another, which lead into some exploring of the DB structure. A specific question arose:

In localised content elements (tt_content entries with sys_language_uid = 1), the fields `t3_origuid` and `l18n_parent` are redundantly filled. `l18n_parent` is required for the backend localisation view to work.

Do they always have the same value? Or is there a use case where the values of the fields can differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those fields can have different values.

`t3_origuid` is a generic field pointing to a record from which the current one was derived in some way. For example by copying or localizing it. [Here](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Ctrl/Index.html#origuid) is some documentation for it.

The field `l18n_parent` is reserved for localization purposes.

Comment: So for a localisation to work, it's only necessary to have `l18n_parent` right?

Answer (score 5):

### l10n_parent / l18n_parent

The field configured in TCA as `transOrigPointerField` (usually `l10n_parent` or `l18n_parent`) is used for localization.
It always contains an id of the record in the default language (even if the record was translated from a record in non-default language), see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/singlehtml/#transorigpointerfield

### t3_origuid

The field configured in TCA as `origUid` (usually `t3_origuid`) is filled when record is copied or translated, and contains an id of the source record, see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/singlehtml/#origuid

The fields will have the same value in some cases (e.g. translating a record from default language), but in other will have different value. E.g. when copying a record on the same page `t3_origuid` will be different than the `l10n_parent`.

To allow localization it is required to have `transOrigPointerField` (`l10n_parent`). Having `origUid` (`t3_origuid`) field is not hard requirement but a good practice as as some additional features may require it to work. Especially in newer versions of TYPO3. For example the Translation Wizard is currently using `t3_origuid` field.

### l10n_source (since TYPO3 8.6)

Since TYPO3 8.6 a new database field `l10n_source` for `tt_content` table has been introduced together with a new TCA ctrl configuration `translationSource`. The `translationSource` field contains an uid of the record used as a translation source, no matter whether the record was translated in the free or connected mode.

see more in the [documentation on l10n_source field](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.6/Feature-78169-IntroduceTranslationSourceFieldForTt_content.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just as a addition to **Jost's** post:

To determine which field you should use check the value of:
`$TCA['tx_yourtable']['ctrl']['transOrigPointerField']`

ie. for `tt_content` it's:

```
$TCA['tt_content']['ctrl']['transOrigPointerField'] = 'l18n_parent';
```